# Drupal 8 : sidebar in node.html.twig

Tags: drupal, twig, drupal-8

Is it possible to call a sidebar in node.html.twig in Drupal 8?

Something like that :

```
 <article{{ attributes }}>

  {{ title_prefix }}
  {% if not page %}
    <h2{{ title_attributes }}>
      <a href="{{ url }}" rel="bookmark">{{ label }}</a>
    </h2>
  {% endif %}
  {{ title_suffix }}

  {% if display_submitted %}
    <footer>
      {{ author_picture }}
      <div{{ author_attributes }}>
        {% trans %}Submitted by {{ author_name }} on {{ date }}{% endtrans %}
        {{ metadata }}
      </div>
    </footer>
  {% endif %}

  <div{{ content_attributes }}>
    {{ content }}
  </div>
 <div{{ content_attributes }}>
    {{ sidebar}}
  </div>
```

I would like to display a different sidebar for each node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this solution found here http://atendesigngroup.com/blog/making-region-content-available-node-templates-drupal-8:

```
/**
* Implements hook_preprocess_node() for NODE document templates.
*/
function THEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  // Allowed view modes
  $view_mode = $variables['view_mode']; // Retrieve view mode
  $allowed_view_modes = ['full']; // Array of allowed view modes (for performance so as to not execute on unneeded nodes)

  // If view mode is in allowed view modes list, pass to THEME_add_regions_to_node()
  if(in_array($view_mode, $allowed_view_modes)) {
    // Allowed regions (for performance so as to not execute for unneeded region)
    $allowed_regions = ['primary_content'];
    THEME_add_regions_to_node($allowed_regions, $variables);
  }
}

/**
* THEME_add_regions_to_node
*/

function THEME_add_regions_to_node($allowed_regions, &$variables) {
  // Retrieve active theme
  $theme = \Drupal::theme()->getActiveTheme()->getName();

  // Retrieve theme regions
  $available_regions = system_region_list($theme, 'REGIONS_ALL');

  // Validate allowed regions with available regions
  $regions = array_intersect(array_keys($available_regions), $allowed_regions);

  // For each region
  foreach ($regions as $key => $region) {

    // Load region blocks
    $blocks = entity_load_multiple_by_properties('block', array('theme' => $theme, 'region' => $region));

    // Sort ‘em
    uasort($blocks, 'Drupal\block\Entity\Block::sort');

    // Capture viewable blocks and their settings to $build
    $build = array();
    foreach ($blocks as $key => $block) {
      if ($block->access('view')) {
        $build[$key] = entity_view($block, 'block');
      }
    }

    // Add build to region
    $variables[$region] = $build;
  }
}
```

I used this hook to override node. You can pass {{ primary_content }} in your node.html.twig